# Export C API limitations in run-time

Tags: c, runtime, modularity

I'm writting a C API for a embedded linux device. My problem is that the software must be portable ( run in diferent platforms ) without any further tweak. It would be good to not use compile time keys ( #ifdefs ).

The problem is that I need to export some capabilities from the hardware and APIs below mine. This should be done in run-time.

Say, I've a struct to define a XYZ position, but the range can be diferent,
the Z sometimes cannot be set. Besides that, it would be good to return a string with the reason.

```
struct position {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    };

int go_to_position(struct position *next_position)
{
    /* Do stuff */
    return (0);
};
```

But suppose in some contexts I can change only x and y. In others, only y and z.

I wonder the best way to implement this, and if there is a know pattern.

I would do something like this:

```
   #define PARAM_COUNT 3

    enum { PARAM_X, PARAM_Y, PARAM_Y }; 

    char*error_strings [PARAM_COUNT][PARAM_COUNT] = {
    {"X don't work", Null , Null },
    {Null, Null, "Z * Y cannot be larger than 10" },
    {Null, "Z * Y cannot be larger than 10", Null },
    };

    char * check_position(struct position *position_to_check) 
    {
           if( INTERNAL_CONSTRAINT(position_to_check->z, position_to_check->y))  {
             return(error_strings[PARAM_Z][ PARAM_Y]);
      }   
          if( INTERNAL_X_NOT_AVAILABLE() )
              return(error_strings[PARAM_X][ PARAM_X]); 
    }
    return (Null);
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this ? Any Ideas ?

Comment: Take a look at the Abstract Factory pattern as well as something called the Dependency Injection pattern. The first thing I would do is to reduce the requirements. For instance instead of "any platforms" could you instead say any Linux platform derived from Debian? The next question would be what are the capabilities of the underlying hardware and software and whether you can probe those components at run time to determine their capabilities. As a possible model, Microsoft DirectX provides a hardware independent interface that adapts to a wide variety of graphics hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you will have some additional API function to check the underlying capabilities.

For example, you may implement a function that will look like this :

```
QueryCapabilities( CAPABILITIES_XYZ, &capa );
```

Where `capa` is a structure containing various information about XZY ranges and availability (or whatever you need).
The higher level using this API will just have to check the capabilities, and adapt or fail depending on what is required.

Another point is what your API will do when given not-perfect parameters. One common approach is 'do your best', where your API will do what it can with the provided parameters. This can include ignoring unsupported parameters and capping out of range value (if max X is 10, 11 will be set to 10). You may make the function fail if a vital parameter is invalid. One other approach is to fail as soon as a parameter is not valid, because it indicates that the upper program is doing non-sense. You can also implement a 'do your best', but return a warning value when something is not OK.